# django save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to use an inlineformset to create a parent model and some children models. Below is my view. The code works in saving the initial Rfq model to the database, but errors when it tries to save the lines inlineformset. This is a one-to-many relationship, but is done using the ForeignKey field.

```
# views.py
def rfq_create(request):
    form = RfqForm(request.POST or None)
    RfqFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Rfq, Rfqlines, form=RfqlinesForm, extra=5, can_delete=True)
    lines_formset = RfqFormSet(request.POST or None)
    title = "Create a new RFQ"
    context = {
        "title": title,
        "form": form,
        "lines_formset": lines_formset,
    }

    if form.is_valid() and lines_formset.is_valid():
        rfq = form.save(commit=False)
        rfq.user = request.user
        rfq.save()
        lines_formset.save()
        rfq_list = Rfq.objects.order_by('rfq_id')[:20]
        title = "RFQ List"
        context = {
            "title": title,
            "rfq_list": rfq_list
        }
        return render(request, "rfq.html", context)

    return render(request, "rfq_create.html", context)
```

I've tried looking at the official Django docs, but it doesn't seem to apply ... or isn't that straightforward anyways.

Here is my traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/rfq/create

Django Version: 1.8.7
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'django.forms.formsets',
 'jquery',
 'crispy_forms',
 'registration',
 'home',
 'rfq',
 'dashboard',
 'pipeline')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/brandon/employees/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/brandon/employees/rfq/views.py" in rfq_create
  36.         lines_formset.save()
File "/home/brandon/employees/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save
  636.         return self.save_existing_objects(commit) + self.save_new_objects(commit)
File "/home/brandon/employees/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save_new_objects
  767.             self.new_objects.append(self.save_new(form, commit=commit))
File "/home/brandon/employees/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save_new
  900.             obj.save()
File "/home/brandon/employees/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  685.                         "unsaved related object '%s'." % field.name

Exception Type: ValueError at /rfq/create
Exception Value: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'rfq'.
```

Comment: can you post your models?

Comment: Kris, I'll add them when I get home to see if that helps.

Comment: Here are the models

https://dpaste.de/HpDw

Comment: Shouldn't the user field be: `user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)`

Answer (score 11):

The answer to the problem was this

```
lines_formset = RfqFormSet(request.POST or None, instance=form.instance)
```

the form.instance was the key that was overlooked.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass your parent model instance to the inline_formset.

See [this relevant section of the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-an-inline-formset-in-a-view), for more info.

Example:

```
lines_formset = RfqFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=rfq)
```

This is necessary so Django can appropriately set the ForeignKey relationships of the child models.

Comment: I'm still confused. The example you posted (aka the one from the official Docs) looks to inherit the Author instance from the request. This led me to believe that the example was creating children Books for a preexisting Author parent model. 

My situation is one in which the parent and the children are created at the SAME time. So I wouldn't really have an instance yet to pass to the inlineformset.

Are you suggesting it should look more like this? https://dpaste.de/eNKV

Comment: I can't view that site due to certificate issues. However, I have an answer to your question. You are creating both simultaneously, but not at the **exact** time. The key is--on the POST request--you should create the parent instance first, save it, and then assign that instance to the child formset. Since the code is executed sequentially, the child instances would then be able to get the unique ID of the parent, and set it as the ForeignKey before being saved themselves.