# Cannot save new users due to ValueError, Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm saving business hours to restaurants when they sign up on my platform but, I'm getting this error: "ValueError: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object restaurant."

It was working prior and changed after I dropped my tables to start a new migration. Here is where the error is pointing to:

```
def restaurant_sign_up(request):
    user_form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
    restaurant_form = RestaurantForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

    if request.method == "POST":
        if user_form.is_valid() and restaurant_form.is_valid():
            new_user = User.objects.create_user(**user_form.cleaned_data)
            new_restaurant = restaurant_form.save(commit=False)

            new_restaurant.user = new_user
            new_restaurant.save()

            login(request, authenticate(
                username = user_form.cleaned_data["username"],
                password = user_form.cleaned_data["password"],

            ))

            for i in range(1, 8):
                OpeningHours.objects.create(
                    restaurant=new_restaurant,
                    day_of_week=i,
                    opening_time="08:00",
                    closing_time="22:00"
                )


            return redirect(restaurant_home)

    return render(request, 'restaurant/signup.html', {
        "user_form": user_form,
        "restaurant_form": restaurant_form,
    # "hours_form": hours_form
    })
```

The traceback points to the "closing_time="22:00"" as the issue. The hours of operations should just be created by default when

This is how the models are set up:

```
class OpeningHours(models.Model):
    WEEKDAYS = [
        (1, _("Monday")),
        (2, _("Tuesday")),
        (3, _("Wednesday")),
        (4, _("Thursday")),
        (5, _("Friday")),
        (6, _("Saturday")),
        (7, _("Sunday")),
     ]

    day_of_week = models.IntegerField(choices=WEEKDAYS)
    opening_time = models.TimeField()
    closing_time = models.TimeField()
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey('buddysapp.Restaurant', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_day_of_week_display()

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='restaurant')
    restaurant_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to= 'restaurant_logo/', blank=False)


    #Location
    street_address = models.CharField(default = '',max_length = 50, null = True)
    city = models.CharField(default='', max_length = 254,null=True,blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(default = '',max_length=25, null = True)
    zip_Code = models.IntegerField(null=False, default='')
    lat = models.FloatField(default = "0.0", blank=True)
    lng = models.FloatField(default = "0.0", blank=True)
    latlng = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)



    def __str__(self):
        return self.restaurant_name

     ## Geocode using full address
    def _get_full_address(self):
        return u'%s %s %s %s' % (self.street_address, self.city, self.state, self.zip_Code)
    full_address = property(_get_full_address)


    def super(Restaurant, self).save(*args, **kwargs):
        if not self.latlng:
                    geolocator = Nominatim()
                    location = geolocator.geocode(self.full_address)
                    self.lat = location.latitude
                    self.lng = location.longitude
                    self.latlng = (location.latitude, location.longitude)
        else:
                 location = '+'.join(filter(None, (self.street_address, self.city, self.state, self.zip_Code)))
                 self.latlng = get_lat_lng(location)
                 super(Restaurant, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503947/django-save-prohibited-to-prevent-data-loss-due-to-unsaved-related-object#34539726

Comment: No. I'm not using InLineformset_factory here

Comment: I don't understand at all what you've done with `super()` in the method declaration there. What in Alasdair's comment led you to think that was the right thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Restaurant` method does not call `super(Restaurant, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` in the `if not self.latlng` branch. That means that the restarant is not saved to the database, so using it in `OpeningHours.objects.create(...)` will give an error.

Comment: super(Restaurant, self).save(*args, **kwargs) I get an syntax Error with the ".save(*args, **kwargs):

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: When I made the update and changed to super(Restaurant, self).save(*args, **kwargs), I'm getting a SyntaxError after ".save"

Comment: I still don't understand your comment. I don't know what update you mean. If you have an error, please include the full traceback and the code that causes it in the question.

Comment: `def save(self, *args, **kwargs):` was fine. Changing it to `def super(Restaurant, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` is completely wrong.

Comment: I got it now. I didn't understand what you meant the first time.